# Hide content-box on specific pages (in admin)?

Tags: admin, content, text

Is this possible to do somehow?

In some pages i use a custom box plugin and i don't need to show the content box on some of those pages. Is it possible to hide it by page template? Or ID if template is not possible?

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using userabuser's answer with a small modification, because global $post doesn't seem to exist on init. You can instead just query for `post` in querystring, like so:

```
function remove_editor() {
    if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
        $id = $_GET['post'];
        $template = get_post_meta($id, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($template == 'template_name.php'){ 
            remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_editor');
```

Answer (score 5):

add this to functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'remove_content_editor');

function remove_content_editor() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'posttype', 'editor' );
}
```

Replace posttype with the name of the post type. It will remove the content editor from that post type's pages

Answer (score 1):

To remove the editor based on template, you may do something like;

```
add_action('init', 'remove_editor');

function remove_editor() {
    global $post;
    $template = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

    //change 'page' to whatever post type you want to apply this to.
    if($template == 'template_name.php'){ 
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems about right, i'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me. (either specific pages or template)

```
add_action('admin_init', 'hide_editor');

function hide_editor() {    
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];

    if (!isset($post_id))
        return;
    // Hide the editor on the page titled 'Press and services' pages
    $hide_page = get_the_title($post_id);
    if ($hide_page == 'press') {
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
    if ($hide_page == 'Services') {
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
    // Hide the editor on a page with a specific page template
    // Get the name of the Page Template file.
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);
    //---
    if ($template_file == 'template-press.php') { // the filename of the page template
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
    if ($template_file == 'template-service.php') { // the filename of the page template
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}
```